# Unable to populate WinForms DataGridView from Entity Data Model without using .ToList() - What is the correct design pattern to use?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, lazy-loading

Following the instructions in this [Entity Framework with WinForms tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html), in Visual Studio 2013 I:

1. Create a fresh solution
2. Add an Entity Data Model, generated from SQL Server Database
3. Add a new Data Source from Object, selecting a table from the Model
4. Drag'n'Drop the new DataSource onto my WinForm thus creating a DataGridView, a BindingSource and a BindingNavigator
5. Add code to instantiate the Entities

   `we = new worldEntities();

   cityBindingSource.DataSource = we.city;`
6. Compile and run

The DGV displays the columns of city but no data. Why do I see no data when the tutorial says I should? (Is this lazy loading or deferred execution?)

If I change the last line to

```
cityBindingSource.DataSource = we.city.ToList();
```

then I see the data in the database. However, if I then make a change to my data:

`var aCity = we.city.Single(c => c.ID == 1);

aCity.Name = "Londinium";

we.SaveChanges();`

Then the data in the database is changed but the DGV still displays the old data.

**How can I get the DGV to update as the data in the model is changed?** Is the design pattern to manually monitor changes and continually call `cityBindingSource.DataSource = we.city.ToList()` ?

Any links to learning materials are also very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my post. Here I explain my method to do this and there is the code. It works very well and its very helpfull to me. [Best approach to bind a datagridview to database entity/ies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117217/best-aproach-to-bind-a-datagridview-to-database-entity-ies)